# Mesclar arrays em php

Tags: php, array-multidimensional

Alguém conhece algo que transformo isso:

```
$name = [0=>'name1',1=>'name2'];
$email = [0=>'email1',1=> 'email2'];
```

nisso aqui?

```
$data = [ 
0 => ['name'=>'name1', 'email'=>'email1'],
1 => ['name'=>'name2', 'email'=>'email2']
];
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu realmente queria ver mais um daqueles truques mirabolantes que resolveria o problema sem iterar mas, se não for um um problema:

```
foreach( $names as $offset => $name ) {
    $data[] = array( 'name' => $name, 'email' => $emails[ $offset ] );
}
```

Só tem um pequeno problema nessa abordagem: Se o segundo array, com os e-mails tiver menos elementos que o de nomes, vários Notices irão aparecer com referência à índices não definidos.

Caso não hajam meios de trazer ambos os arrays com o mesmo comprimento (como uma JOIN que popule o lado direito com NULLs), você pode equalizá-los. Há um tempo atrás eu criei uma e ficou assim:

```
/**
 * Equalize array lengths
 *
 * The shorter array will receive as many NULL elements as needed
 * to have the same length of the larger array.
 *
 * Both arguments are optional, so this function can be used to
 * create dummy arrays based upon other array length
 *
 * And both arguments must be passed as reference, so the changes
 * can be applied
 *
 * @param array|optional $a
 *   First Array
 *
 * @param array|optional $b
 *   Second Array
 */
function equalize( array &$a = array(), array &$b = array() ) {

    $l1 = count( $a );
    $l2 = count( $b );

    if( $l1 == $l2 ) {
        return;
    }

    if( $l1 > $l2 ) {

        $b = array_merge( $b, array_fill( 0, ( $l1 - $l2 ), NULL ) );

    } else {

        $a = array_merge( $a, array_fill( 0, ( $l2 - $l1 ), NULL ) );
    }
}
```

Para usar basta:

```
equalize( $array1, $array2 );
```

No caso eu iterei o array de nomes pois, teoricamente, nomes são requeridos e e-mails opcionais, mas se você quiser inverter, tudo bem também.

Depois de equalizados, você pode, ainda, ignorar completamente qual arrays iterar. Mas óbvio que, nesse caso, a iteração mudaria também:

```
foreach( $emails as $offset => $email ) {
    $data[] = array( 'name' => $names[ $offset ], 'email' => $email );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Se você realmente precisar nomear as chaves da forma indicada, as outras respostas são todas boas opções. Contudo, se os tamanhos das duas arrays sempre forem iguais e os valores estiverem alinhados, existe ainda outra possibilidade bem mais simples, mas que exigiria uma reavaliação do seu paradigma, que é simplesmente utilizar a função "array_combine".

```
$name = [0=>'name1',1=>'name2'];     // array com as chaves
$email = [0=>'email1',1=> 'email2']; // array com os valores

$comb = array_combine($name, $email);
```

O resultado seria:

```
Array
(
    [nome1]  => email1
    [nome2]  => email2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que as variáveis são sincronizadas uma a outra, então nunca terão quantidades diferentes, prevendo isso basta fazer:

```
$name = [0=>'name1',1=>'name2'];
$email = [0=>'email1',1=> 'email2'];


foreach($name as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = array('name' => $value, 'email' => $email[$key]);
}

print_r($data);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => name1
            [email] => email1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => name2
            [email] => email2
        )

)
```