# Unir arrays php alocando valores combinados entre as duas

Tags: php, array

Tenho os seguintes arrays:

```
$corretor = array(
  'Carlos',
  'Andre',
  'Rosinei',
  'Vinicius',
  'Thales'
);
$comissao = array(
   5,
   3,
   3,
   3,
   2
);
```

Como faço para unir ambos, imprimindo resultado da seguinte forma:

> Carlos - 5% | Andre  - 3% | Rosinei - 3% | Vinicius - 3% | Thales   - 2%

Comment: Você só quer unir o resultado para exibir, ou quer criar também um novo array com os dados em "merge"?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27631/mesclar-arrays-em-php

Comment: @DiegoF obrigado por ajudar, a reposta do Sergio era exatamente o que precisava.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partindo do principio que ambas as arrays têm o mesmo numero de elementos tens de criar uma maneira de iterar essas arrays e usar o index da iteração para usar dados de cada uma.

Se usares o [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) nem precisas de saber o index de iteração e podes misturar as duas diretamente assim:

```
function misturar($nome, $perc){
    return $nome.' - '.$perc.'%';   
}

$c = array_map("misturar", $corretor, $comissao);
echo implode($c, ' | ');
```

#### Exemplo: https://ideone.com/ck4nFA

Apesar de neste caso achar mais simples com array_map, também podes fazer assim:

```
$res = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($corretor); $i++){
    $res.= $corretor[$i].' - '.$comissao[$i].'% | ';    
}

echo substr($res, 0, -3);
```

Exemplo: https://ideone.com/TyoYzm

Comment: era exatamente isso. Existe alguma forma de eliminar valores em branco do array?

Comment: @IgorSilva referes-te a casos onde ambas as arrays tem um valor em branco na mesma posição?

Comment: Se fôr esse o caso podes usar o `array_filter()` assim: https://ideone.com/OFbyLl para o primeiro caso, e assim para o segundo:  https://ideone.com/O5UmFI

Comment: Realmente resolveu o meu problema. Agradeço pela força!